# problemas con el botón de pausa de mi proyecto de reproductor mp3

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

hola amigos espero de todo corazón se encuentren muy bien.

estoy creando un reproductor de mp3 en python y aunque considero que ya he avanzado bastante tengo un problema y es que el botón de pausa no cumple con su función correctamente  ya que no pausa, solo detiene la canción y con un segundo click no reanuda la reproducción donde se quedo, solo no funciona tengo presionar play nuevamente y la canción vuelve a comenzar desde el inicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son las librerías que importe

```
import tkinter as tk 
import fnmatch
import os
from typing import Pattern
from pygame import mixer



def pause_song():
    if pauseButton['text']== 'pause':
        mixer.music.pause()
        pauseButton['text']=='play'
    else:
        mixer.music.unpause()
        pauseButton['text']= 'pause
```

Comment: El código de la función tiene un problema. En la linea `pauseButton['text']=='play'` NO estás cambiando el texto del botón, estás preguntando si el texto del boton es igual a 'play'. Si esa linea es así en tu código original, no habrás querido decir  `pauseButton['text']='play'`? Eso podría ser la causa del problema. Comentame como te fue porfa!

Comment: @DanteS. hola camarada! antes que nada gracias por el consejo, me sirvió bastante pero lo resolví quitando '=' pero en la linea de código de pause  `def pause_song():
    if pauseButton['text']== 'pause':
        mixer.music.pause()
        pauseButton['text']='play'
    else:
        mixer.music.unpause()
        pauseButton['text']= 'pause'`

Comment: perdon por la demora pero me agripe un poco y no pude contestar antes, ahora estoy viendo si puedo hacer funcionar correctamente los botones de prev y next, intentare resolverlo solo antes de venir a molestarles nuevamente... muchas gracias por su apollo

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado c: no pasa nada por la demora! Y al menos a mi no me molestas con preguntas (de hecho, diria que al contrario). Pero si es buena idea intentar resolverlo por ti mismo primero y luego si no sale preguntar c: